# Best way of Image Uploading to server on Android? (MVVM, Android Arcitecture Components)

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, retrofit2, okhttp

What is the best practice for uploading images from device storage to a server in android with kotlin?
I am currently building a Social Media Network and I'm using Apollo Client with mutations to let the user upload content to the database.
I want that the image gets uploaded from the storage to my server (hosting provider is Hostinger) and that the url to the image is stored with other data like name, caption etc is stored on my MySQL Database.
The second part (storing the link to my Database) is working fine, I do it with the GraphQL mutation.
But I'm not sure what the best practice for the first part is (uploading images from storage to the server).

I heard many things so far:
PHP Script,
Retrofit2,
OkHttp.
But some of these articles or tutorials are 5+ years old.

What is currently a good approach to do it, are there some good librarys for it?

Comment: Activity UI Action => ViewModel  => WorkManager => Network Request to Upload Image. (pattern can differ as per needs.)

Comment: Activity UI -> VM or Presenter -> UseCase -> Repository -> NetworkDatasource and DatabaseDatasource (Repository pattern contains the flow logic to fetch data and save data)

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is an option resize the image
2. Shrink images size with [zelory library](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor)
3. Convert image file to Base64 (It converts any file to encoded string)
4. You can upload your Base64 string file image with Retrofit2, OkHttp, Google uses Moshi library for parsing JSON data in [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-getting-data-internet?hl=en#0) codelab

(Use coroutines to do image processes. You should not block the main threat.)